# initWithCoder shows wrong frame in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard

I am using storyboard in my project. Storyboard has a custom view with auto layout.

CustomView.h

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {

        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.frame.size.width);   //Returns wrong
        NSLog (@"view: %f", self.bounds.size.width);  //Returns wrong
}
return self;
}
```

If i run the app, it shows wrong frame.

Help me to solve this

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong"? What did you expect and what did you get?

Comment: @justMartin, if I run in iPhone6 then it should return 375 instead of 320.

Comment: Wrong compared to what? Do you mean that your View looks different in Interface Builder and on actual device/simulator?

Comment: @NKorotkov,  if I run in iPhone6 then it should return 375 instead of 320

Comment: You've probably set up constraints wrong - to fixed width. How does it look on the device? View appears not taking up all the screen's width?

Comment: @NKorotkov, yes, it shows wrong frame.

Comment: Show us how it looks and explain what you wanted to see. Provide constraints for that view too - I'm pretty sure they are wrong.

Comment: Why should it return 375? Have you set height/width constraints in interface builder? The thing is, that after loading a view from a xib the frame will be the frame you set in interface builder. You can define constraints, but you can modify the views frame anyways. You will see the "yellow arrow" then. In the initWithCoder method the view's size will be the same as in the xib file. Autolayouting will be executed after that. Maybe that's what causes the confusion ;-)

Comment: Given that a view's frame is dependent on the views it is a subview of and the constraints setup across the entire view hierarchy, the only safe place to acquire frame sizes is from `viewWillAppear` or later once full layout has happened.

Answer (score 2):

Because in `initWithCoder`,the `constraints` has not been applied to the view.

Example:

[image]

Code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    NSLog (@"viewDidAppear: %f", self.testview.frame.size.width);
}
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    NSLog (@"viewDidLayoutSubviews: %f", self.testview.frame.size.width);
}
-(void)awakeFromNib{
    NSLog (@"awakeFromNib: %f", self.testview.frame.size.width);
}
-(instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        NSLog (@"initWithCoder: %f", self.testview.frame.size.width);
    }
    return self;
}
```

And log

```
2015-06-11 19:09:27.647 OCTest[717:20692] initWithCoder: 0.000000
2015-06-11 19:09:27.649 OCTest[717:20692] awakeFromNib: 0.000000
2015-06-11 19:09:27.696 OCTest[717:20692] viewDidLayoutSubviews: 320.000000
2015-06-11 19:09:27.746 OCTest[717:20692] viewDidAppear: 320.000000
```

Comment: I have use custom view i.e. subclass of UIVIew & viewDidLayoutSubviews not called in it.

Comment: I know.Just from the aspect of UIViewController to tell you that in initWithCoder,it is too early to get the frame.

Comment: When the super view layout subview,the constraints is applied. Only after that,you can get the right frame

Comment: So, what to do with custom view loads from storyboard directly

Answer (score -1):

I met the same problem, if you want to take the size of screen in InitWithCoder method - take it this way

```
CGFloat x = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
CGFloat y = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
```

Not from the still-not-existing bounds of the UIView, but out of the UIScreen.